# Unable to run ASP.NET projects in 64 bit mode on Windows 10 install with VS 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, windows-10

We have recently (yesterday) upgraded to Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

Our ASP.NET project will run absolutely fine if we compile to "Any CPU".

We've now tested it on 2 different machines, compiling to x64 produces the error

```
Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'OurDLL' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I have been searching for quite a while and most of the troubleshooting I find is for the reverse problem. That is, someone is trying to run a 32 bit ASP app on a 64 bit machine and receiving this error.

I've done everything like deleting all the obj, bin folders etc.

I've also deleted all the temporary .NET files on the computer and also ran aspnet_regiis.exe from the Framework64 directory.

Has anyone experienced this?

Edit: Confirmed with a 3rd person/3rd machine that ASP.NET project do not work in Windows 10 with VS2015 while compiling to x64. It's starting to look like a VS2015 bug.

Answer (score 11):

You have to enable 64x for your projects

Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects -> Ok

[image: VisualStudioToolsOptions]

[image: WebProjectFor64bit]

This will enable 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

We had checked this a few times, so evidently it got reverted back to default at some point, and VS *still* doesn't give a warning or an option to change this option during compiling.

Anyway:

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects > 'Use the 64 bit 
version of IIS Express for websites and projects'
```

Though we had checked this, I decided to check again.

So in case you are upgrading to VS2015/Windows 10, and using an ASP.NET project, you may want to check this setting a few times especially if you do any .NET updates/Web Tools/VS repairs.